# Show $\int _ { 0 } ^ { \infty } \frac { x \sin x } { \left( x ^ { 2 } + 1 \right) ^ { 2 } } dx = \frac { \pi } { 4 e }$ with residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

> **Problem**: Compute $\int _ { 0 } ^ { \infty } \frac { x \sin x } { \left( x ^ { 2 } + 1 \right) ^ { 2 } }  dx = \frac { \pi } { 4 e }$

First we can study $\int_{\Gamma_R}g(z)dz$ where $\Gamma_R$ is the upper half circle of radius $R$ and $g(z)=\frac{z}{(z^2+1)^2}e^{iz}$.
The singularity in the upper half circle is $z_0 = i$. If we prove that the integral over the contour is $0$, we could conclude with the following result :

$$\int_{\Gamma_R}g(z)dz=\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^{R}g(x)dx = 2\pi i (Res_{z_0}(g))=(2\pi i)\frac{1}{2e}=\frac{i\pi}{e}$$

And by keeping the imaginary part of the solution, we get that :

$$\int _ { -\infty } ^ { \infty } \frac { x \sin x } { \left( x ^ { 2 } + 1 \right) ^ { 2 } }  dx = \frac { \pi } { e }$$

Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to compute the integral from $0$ to $\infty$, also I tried to show that the integral over the contour was equal to 0 without much success.

Comment: The given function is an even function.

Comment: Well the integrand is even. But that means your solutions is wrong by a factor of $2$.

Comment: @mrtaurho I found my mistake, $z_0$ is a pole of order 2 and I used the formula as it was pole of order 1.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3061857/399334) answer, combined with @mrtaurho comment about using $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\text{even integrand})\mathrm dz=2\int_{0}^\infty (\text{even integrand})\mathrm dz$$ should help you find the errors.

Comment: @JohnDoe Perfect thank you very much for the link, sorry for the repost.